# how can create a flutter project with org in vscode?

Tags: command-line, flutter, visual-studio-code

every time I want to create a flutter project in vscode it only gives me the option of placing the name for example "myapp"

so the name of the app is "com.example.myapp".Is there any way to change that "com.example" without having to create the app and have to rename all the files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change your `flutter create organization` in your preference settings.

click **file > preferences > settings** and search for `flutter create organization`. Edit your settings.json file and add this `"dart.flutterCreateOrganization": "com.<your_domain>"` e.g com.nonybrighto. It will use that when creating a new flutter project.